# API returning Complex JSON Which Needs to Map TypeScript Class

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a API which is returning a complex JSON and I want to consume that API in Angular-v5 using HTTPClient. I have successfully consumed that API, but the problem is when I want to extract Collections serialized in JSON and map to local arrays in TypeScript then it throws error of undefined for local array and when I try to access the **PolicyDetail** (which is a Typescript class) properties navigating through like **policydetail.policyForms** then it throws undefined error, and cannot be used in HTML template that's why.
Although it **PolicyDetail.name** and other properties works except collections.

**Note: API Response is coming and I have tested in Swagger and also seen in Network tap.**

**Model Coming From API**

```
  public class PolicyDetailViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PolicyDataViewModel> Purpose { get; set; } = new List<PolicyDataViewModel>();
    public ICollection<PolicyDataViewModel> Objectives { get; set; } = new List<PolicyDataViewModel>();
    public ICollection<DefinitionTermViewModel> Definitions { get; set; } = new List<DefinitionTermViewModel>();
    public ICollection<PolicyReferenceViewModel> References { get; set; } = new List<PolicyReferenceViewModel>();
    public ICollection<PolicyDataViewModel> Policy { get; set; } = new List<PolicyDataViewModel>();
    public ICollection<PolicyDataViewModel> Procedure { get; set; } = new List<PolicyDataViewModel>();
    public ICollection<FormViewModel> Forms { get; set; } = new List<FormViewModel>();
    public string SupportingInformation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PolicyDataViewModel> Outstanding { get; set; } = new List<PolicyDataViewModel>();
    public ICollection<int> SelectedPackages { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public ICollection<int> SelectedRegions { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public bool AnyChanges { get; set; }
    public bool IsNewPolicy { get; set; }
}
```

**TypeScript Class**

```
export class PolicyDetail extends AuditableBase
{
name:string;
ref:string;
policyInfo:string;
keyFactsForStaff: string;

policyDataDetails: Array<PolicyDataDetail> = new Array<PolicyDataDetail>(); 
policyDefinitionTerms: Array<PolicyDefinitionTerm>= new Array<PolicyDefinitionTerm>();
policyreferences: Array<PolicyReference> = new Array<PolicyReference>();
policyForms: Array<PolicyForm> = new Array<PolicyForm>();

selectedKloes: Array<number> = new Array <number>();
selectedRegions: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
selectedClusters: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
selectedLegislations: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
}
```

**Maping Result of HttpRequest To TypeScript**

```
export class PolicyDetailComponent {
public policy: PolicyDetail = new PolicyDetail();
public forms: Array<PolicyForm> = new Array<PolicyForm>();
public policyId: number;
constructor(private policyDetailSvc: PolicyDetailSvc,
    private router: Router) { }

getPolicyDetail() {
    this.policyDetailSvc.getPolicy(this.policyId).subscribe((result) => {
        this.policy = result,//it works
            this.forms = result.policyForms; // it doesn't
        console.log(result, 'Result - Subscribed'),//it works and shows complete object in JSON
        console.log(this.policy, 'This.Policy- Subscribed'),//it works and shows complete object in JSON
        console.log(this.forms, 'Forms'),//undefined
            console.log(result.policyForms, 'Result Forms'),//undefined
        console.log(result.policyreferences, 'Result References')//undefined
    });
}
}
```

**Problem is Mapping Forms Arrays and other collection objects**

1. I tried using Local property of forms: PolicyForm[]; but it throws undefined.
2. I tried accessing Policy.PolicyForms but it also throws undefined

I think I'm taking Typescript as C#, but don't know where I am making mistakes.

If my question is not clear then kindly let me know, I'll clear any other confusion.

[image: JSON Data Coming From API]

Comment: You couldn't supply the raw JSON response could you?

Comment: I have response coming from API into Angular app and I can show the PolicyName into HTML template but I want to show PolicyForms which is an collection and successfully coming from API but couldn't supply to HTML template with undefined error.

Comment: It seems your problem is incorrect run-time access of the response object, rather than the TypeScript type declarations (compile-time concern).

Comment: @RobertPenner Yes it seems and I'm testing it now. I have **forms** in JSON but trying to access that using **policyForms**. I think it might be the mistake.

Comment: @RobertPenner you are absolutely right. It was the problem. I got it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was accessing the response with wrong collection names, I was getting **Forms** but I was trying to access using **PolicyForms**. 
So I change the **PolicyForms** to **Forms** and end so on and it is working as perfectly it should be.

```
 this.forms = result.policyForms;//it was not working because JSON response was coming forms:[], not PolicyForms:[].
this.forms=result.forms;//
```

Answer (score 3):

## Parsing

From what I can see in your question, if you have a raw JSON string in your response, you need to parse it into a JavaScript object...

```
const policyDetail = JSON.parse(result);
```

This will work if the result is a string, containing a JSON serialization.

## C# Land vs TypeScript Land

Another issue you may find is that your C# class has names such as `Name` and `Ref`, so if you are serializing with these names, you'll need to match the casing in the TypeScript...

```
this.forms = result.PolicyForms
//                  ^
```

Comment: Your suggested solution causes this error: "Argument of type 'PolicyDetail' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string".
Because I have used HttpClient with Typed response. httpclient.get<PolicyDetail>();
Let me add snapshot of JSON response in question.

Comment: I have serialized in proper JSON format and attached image containing JSON result. It is not complete result but the minimum to show you the result.